# Search many fields with will_paginate / searchlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, searchlogic

How do you effectively search among many fields in a model?

```
# user.rb model
def self.search(search, page)  
  paginate :per_page => 20, :page => page,
  :conditions => 
    ['name like ? OR notes like ? OR code like ? OR city like ? OR state like ?,
    "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%"
    ], :order => 'name'
```

This code is horrible for any more than a few fields, and it doesn't return a result if, for instance word #1 comes from :name and word #2 comes from :code. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You know what, good call. I'll break them up.

Comment: The reason the search isn't finding any matches with multiple words is because it is looking for the entire string "word1 word2" in all your columns but is only finding partial matches, so make sure to separate the search terms first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that do work

```
def self.search(search, page)
  fields = [:name, :notes, :code, :city, :state] 
  paginate :per_page => 20, :page => page,
  :conditions => [fields.map{|f| "#{f} like ?"}.join(' OR '),
    *fields.map{|f| "%#{search}%"}], :order => 'name'
```

Comment: Thank you for compressing it so nicely. I tried it with two search terms, where one is from :notes and another from :code and it doesn't work (it wasn't working before either). Is there any way to add results for each search term across fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic)

```
def self.search(search, page)  
  search_cond = resource.search(name_or_notes_or_code_or_city_or_state_like => search.to_s)
  search_cond.all
end
```

Hope you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.search(search, page)
  fields = %w(name notes code city state) 
  paginate :per_page => 20, :page => page,
  :conditions => [fields.map{|f| "#{f} like :phrase"}.join(' OR '), {:phrase => search}], 
  :order => 'name'
```